# Функция reduce в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Пытался написать код с помощью функции reduce,но не получается из-за ошибки. Подскажите пожалуйста,что нужно сделать? (ниже приложен текст ошибки)

```
def func(a, b):
    return a + b

numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
total = reduce(func, numbers, 0)
print(total)
```

Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/<user>/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/main.py", line 5, in <module>
    total = reduce(func, numbers, 0)
NameError: name 'reduce' is not defined
```

Comment: functools в помощь

Comment: В 3-ей версии Питона `reduce` убрали из встроенных функций в библиотеку `functools`. И правильно сделали - она очень редко в общем-то используется. )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Для того чтобы использовать `reduce()` вам необходимо импортировать библиотеку `functools`. Ниже приведён пример.

```
import functools
```

И после подключение прописать `functools.reduce()`

Вторым способом подключение можно взять из functools только `reduce()`

```
from fuctools import reduce
```

Результат будет, использование `reduce()` без прописывание в начале functools

```
reduce()
```

Comment: Большое спасибо за объяснение!